# Architecture: Efficiently calculate and maintain score of user submissions in a Reddit like site

Tags: node.js, web-applications, architecture, redis, software-design

What's an efficient way to calculate and maintain a real time story raking in a Reddit like site that is driven by user submissions?

Each submission has a certain score that is determined by the number of upvotes, downvotes it has received and the time of submission. (Newer submissions get a higher rank). Although I have ideas for implementing the math behind this, I was wondering on how to best architect something like this, so that the score for submissions are computed and maintained accurately.

Does the score re-calculation have to be a periodic task via a background job or does the score be re-computed only on a user action, like a vote.

Running a background job to recalculate the score for every single submission in history at a periodic interval seems to be highly inefficient while re-computing the score only on upvote/downvote/submission does not make for an accurate ranking system (since then it would then be possible for a story to actually loose score on a new upvote).

The code for the web app is written in Node.js and the database I use is Mongo along with Redis, if it matters.

I hope this question is not too general, if it is, kindly let me know how I can make it more precise.

Comment: You can have a look at reddit code and see how they do it and get some ideas: https://github.com/reddit/reddit

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at a company I worked at previously. I think you're right to use redis for storing scores, and you're right about the basic scoring methodology: "an upvote today is worth more than an upvote yesterday, and an upvote yesterday is worth more than an upvote the day before that." You can achieve this by letting upvotes, downvotes, submissions, etc... all have constant scores, but keeping a "current" and "previous" score window for every post, and using the difference between the post's "current" score and "previous" score to calculate its "true" score.

What I mean by this is, let's see we have some post we'll call A, and its gotten 1 upvote in its previous score window, and 1000 upvotes in its current window. You can then tell its obviously trending and give it a very high true score-- say `cur_score/prev_score` or something similar. The same way, if some other post we'll call B had 1000 upvotes in its previous window, but just 1 in its current window, we know its no longer trending and give it a punishingly low true score. This leads to the very nice result that *if a post winds up at the top of the hot feed, it has to get more upvotes right now than it did in the last hour to stay there*, so stuff will only stay at the top of the feed if it's truly trending, and nothing will get stuck there in a feedback loop of seen-more, upvoted-more.

Finally, for the current and previous windows themselves, you can basically roll them over every n minutes by resetting the current window to be blank and setting the previous window equal to the old current window. You can do this cheaply in Redis by storing each window in a hash like `cur_window` and `prev_window` and just `RENAME cur_window prev_window` every n minutes when you're ready to roll over. This is cheap, efficient and hits the point.

Now the above is a rough sketch that doesn't get into every corner case and technicality-- that's beyond the scope of an SO answer-- but it does solve the fundamental problem you're running into of being able to figure out a trending score in a way that scales not limited by number of posts.